# AJAX Return ParseError

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to send an ajax result as a json but google inspector is showing a parse error

**ajax**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    var ajaxUrl = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php')?>";
    var page = 1; // What page we are on.
    var ppp = 3; // Post per page

    $("#misha_loadmore").on("click",function(){ // When btn is pressed.
        $("#misha_loadmore").attr("disabled",true); // Disable the button, temp.
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            cache : false,
            url: ajaxUrl,
            data:{
            "action":"more_post_ajax",
            "offset": (page * ppp) + 1,
            "ppp": ppp},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                page++;
                console.log(data);
                //$(".post-grid-container").append(posts); // CHANGE THIS!
                $("#misha_loadmore").attr("disabled",false);
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log('error:', error);
            }
        });
   });
});
```

**PHP**

```
function more_post_ajax(){
    $offset = $_POST["offset"];
    $ppp = $_POST["ppp"];
    //header("Content-Type: text/html");

    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'oportunity',
        'posts_per_page' => $ppp,
        //'offset'         => $offset
    );

    $loop = new WP_Query($args);

    if ($loop->have_posts()){
        $return = array();

        while ($loop->have_posts()) { 
            $loop->the_post(); 
            
            $return[]=array(
                'points' => get_field('points'),
                'start_date' => get_field('start_date', false, false),
                'image' => the_post_thumbnail(),
                'link' => get_permalink(get_the_ID()),
                'title' => the_title()
            );
        }
        wp_send_json($return);
    }
}
```

**This is part of the message I receive:**

readyState: 4
status: 200
statusText: "parsererror"
responseText: "[{"points":"1450","image":null,"link":"https://test.io/oportunity/headline-2/"},{"points":"1450","image":null,"link":"https://test.io/oportunity/headline-3/"},{"points":"1450","image":null,"link":"https://test.io/oportunity/headline-4/"}]"

Comment: did you try `JSON.parse(data)`  before using it?

Comment: What do you mean by "message I receive"? Where is this originating from?

Comment: @El_Vanja that's what I get with console.log('error:', error);

Comment: If you've reached a solution, you can answer your own question, rather than just adding the part that solves it to the question itself. That way it will be clearer in search that the question has an answer and it will also enable the site filters to treat is as answered.

Answer (score 0):

I'll let this here, in case it's useful for anyone. I changed the json format to html.

**PHP**

```
function more_post_ajax(){
    $offset = $_POST["offset"];
    $ppp = $_POST["ppp"];
    header("Content-Type: text/html");

    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'oportunity',
        'posts_per_page' => $ppp,
        'offset'         => $offset
    );

    $loop = new WP_Query($args);
    ob_start();

    if ($loop->have_posts()){

        while ($loop->have_posts()) { 
            $loop->the_post(); 
            
            $points = get_field('points');
            $user_id = get_current_user_id();
            $balance = mycred_get_users_balance( $user_id );
            
            if( get_field('start_date', false, false) ){
                $start_date = get_field('start_date', false, false);
                $start_date = new DateTime($start_date);
                $date_now = new DateTime();
                $diff = date_diff($date_now, $start_date);  
            }

            
            if($points > $balance ){
                $needpoints = true;
            }?>
            
            <div class="posts-grid">
                            <div class="post-grid-image">
                                <?php echo the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                                <a class="modal-link" href="<?php echo get_permalink(get_the_ID()); ?>">
                                    <div class="img__description
                                    <?php if ($needpoints){
                                        echo "needpoints";
                                    }elseif($diff){
                                        echo "unavailable";
                                    } ?>
                                    ">
                                        <?php if ($needpoints){?>
                                            <p>You Need More Points</p>
                                        <?php }elseif( isset($start_date) ){
                                        ?>
                                            <p>Available in:</br>
                                                <?php 
                                                echo $diff->format("%y Year %m Month %d Day %h Hours %i Minute %s Seconds"); ?>
                                            </p>
                                        <?php }else{?>
                                            <p>View More</p>
                                        <?php }?>

                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="post-content">
                                <div class="post-title">
                                    <h5>Featured Point Opportunity</h5>
                                    <h5>
                                        <?php the_title(); ?>
                                    </h5>
                                </div>
                                <div class="post-points">
                                    <p>
                                        <?php 
                                            $current_post_id = $post->ID;
                                            echo "+" . get_field('points', $current_post_id). " pts"; 
                                        ?>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
        <?php  
        }

        $result = ob_get_contents();
          ob_end_clean();
          $return = array('content' => $result);
          wp_send_json($return);
          wp_die();
    }

}

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_more_post_ajax', 'more_post_ajax'); 
add_action('wp_ajax_more_post_ajax', 'more_post_ajax');
```

**ajax**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    var ajaxUrl = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php')?>";
    var page = 1; // What page we are on.
    var ppp = 3; // Post per page

    $("#misha_loadmore").on("click",function(){ // When btn is pressed.
        $("#misha_loadmore").attr("disabled",true); // Disable the button, temp.
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            cache : false,
            url: ajaxUrl,
            data:{
            "action":"more_post_ajax",
            "offset": (page * ppp),
            "ppp": ppp},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                page++;
                console.log(data);
                $(".post-grid-container").append(data.content); // CHANGE THIS!
                $("#misha_loadmore").attr("disabled",false);
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log('error:', error);
            }
        });
   });
});
```

Answer (score -2):

can you try this?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    var ajaxUrl = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php')?>";
    var page = 1; // What page we are on.
    var ppp = 3; // Post per page

    $("#misha_loadmore").on("click",function(){ // When btn is pressed.
        $("#misha_loadmore").attr("disabled",true); // Disable the button, temp.
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            cache : false,
            url: ajaxUrl,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify({
              "action":"more_post_ajax",
              "offset": (page * ppp) + 1,
              "ppp": ppp}),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                page++;
                console.log(data);
                //$(".post-grid-container").append(posts); // CHANGE THIS!
                $("#misha_loadmore").attr("disabled",false);
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log('error:', error);
            }
        });
   });
});
```

Comment: The error changed, now I get responseText: "0", status: 400, statusText:"error". Is that what you expected?

Comment: No, I thought it should be ok. you are sending over a json. so we stringify it and set contentType: 'application/json'. you have dateType: 'json' which is correct Sorry, I do not know what are wrong.